# Variable is assigned within all cases of a switch but Java says it may not?

Tags: java, compilation, variable-assignment

Why doesn't this Java code compile?

```
class A {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
       boolean b;
       switch(1) {
           case 1:
               b = true;
       }
       System.out.println("b: " + b);
    }
}
```

It's complaining that `b` might not have been initialized, even though it is in all cases as far as I can tell. How could `b` not be initialized?

```
$ javac A.java 
A.java:8: variable b might not have been initialized
       System.out.println("b: " + b);
                                  ^
1 error
```

Answer (score 4):

You need to initialize it beforehand, or add a `default` clause:

```
switch (1) {
case 1:
    b = true;
default:
    b = false;
}
```

It's just not feasible for the JVM to analyze all possible cases, not even for a literal. At least, as @assylias points out, the language specification doesn't demand that it should.

Therefore, from a code analysis standpoint, it has to handle a literal the same way as it would handle a variable, and it can't know that a specific path is always chosen, even here where *we* can easily see that the first case will always match.

So, it needs to see that the variable `b` gets initialized no matter what the value is, and therefore demands a `default` clause.

Comment: Why? Can the match of `1` against `1` fail?

Comment: "*It's just not possible for the JVM to analyze all possible cases*" => it maybe is, but that is not what the language specification says.

Comment: @assylias: Fair. Maybe `feasible` is a better word.

Comment: "From a code analysis standpoint, it has to handle a literal the same way as it would handle a variable" Why?

Comment: @Dog: The second paragraph follows from the first one. Since an analysis isn't made which cases are possible or not, it has to treat it the same way as any other variable.

Comment: concerning the question to match 1 and not 1: try a simple if :-) e.g. if(true) b=true; else b=false; - but there are simpler ways to achieve this

Answer (score 1):

You can refer to [JLS #16.2.9](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-16.html#jls-16.2.9). In particular, without a `default` statement, the compiler can't decide that `b` is definitely assigned after the switch statement, even if it is obvious in your example that it is.